# React Bootstrap 5 popover with HTML content

Tags: reactjs, typescript, bootstrap-5

In React with Typescript I'm trying to get a working Bootstrap 5 popover with HTML content. The following code works with standard "text" content:

```
const popoverRef = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const popover = new bootstrap.Popover(popoverRef.current as HTMLAnchorElement, {
      title: "Sample Title",
      content: "Some sample text content",
      trigger: 'click'
    })
  })

return (
   <a href="#" tabIndex={0} ref={popoverRef}>Popover Test</a>
)
```

But when I try to add HTML content:

```
const popContent = <span>Some sample <strong>HTML</strong> content</span>;

useEffect(() => {
    const popover = new bootstrap.Popover(popoverRef.current as HTMLAnchorElement, {
      title: "Sample Title",
      content: popContent,
      trigger: 'click'
    })
  })
```

I get the following error:

`Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string | Element | JQuery | ((this: HTMLElement) => string | Element | JQuery) | undefined'.`

[image]

I'm not sure how to resolve?

Comment: Please show your error as text. See [ask].

Comment: You haven't wrapped your HTML in quotes. I'm surprised it doesn't barf before that.